# Class Structure for a list Class?

Tags: c#, oop, class, class-design

I am looking for some class structure help.  Lets say I have a class called Dog holds information about the dog (name, weight, type)  but because there could be multiple dogs, I would also like a class to hold all of these dogs, for use throughout my entire project.  Whats the best way to go about doing this?

Just to have a DogList class, that stores the Dog class information into a public list? Allowing me to retrieve it at will?

Or should the list be a static within the original dog class? maybe in the constructor, any time someone creates a new dog, the dog gets put into the static list?

Edit: Sorry question was a bit miss leading
Here is the structure I have so far, wondering if there is a better way to implement.

```
public class Dog
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public int weight { get; set; }
}

public class DogFactory //not sure if thats the correct wording
{
    public List<dog> lstDogs = new List<dog>();
    public void setDogs()
    {
    Animal.Retrieve("Dog"); 
    //will retrieve a list of all dogs, with details, though this is costly to use
        foreach(Animal.Dog pet in Animal._Dogs)
        {
            Dog doggie = new doggie();
            doggie.Name = pet.Name;
            ...etc
            lstDog.add(doggie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say "there could be multiple dogs" do you mean 'multiple instances of class Dog' or 'multiple types of dogs'?

Comment: sorry, multiple instances of class dog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to make a list of dogs is:

`List<Dog>`

This is a strongly-typed list of Dogs using the `List<T>` class from System.Collections.Generic.  You can make a class of this:

`public class DogList : List<Dog>`

Though this is usually not necessary unless you want to add properties specifically to a *list* of Dogs and not the dogs themselves.

UPDATE:

You usually do not need to create a dedicated list class when using `List<T>`.  In most cases, you can do this:

```
public class DogService
{
    public List<Dog> GetAllDogs()
    {
        var r = new Repository(); // Your data repository
        return r.Dogs.ToList();   // assuming your repository exposes a 'Dogs query'
    }
}
```

If you're using LINQ to get your data, you can use the ToList() extension to return a `List<T>`, so no need to create a class that derives from `List<T>`.

Comment: I know how to make a list of dogs, I just don't know where to make it, so that its accessible for any class in the project.  I will need a method to set up the list, should this be in its own class or within the dog class

Comment: Generic lists are convenient because you don't need to declare them all over the place.  In my projects, when I need a list of something (Invoices, Users, whatever) I expose a property or method of List<T> where T is the type I want to return.  If you have a service that returns a list of dogs, make the method return List<Dog>.  If you have a ViewModel that supports a View with a listbox or grid full of dogs, make a property or type List<Dog> and bind the control to that property.

Comment: PS- The only requirement here is that your project have a reference to the 'T' type, whatever type you want to make into a list.  You can then use generic lists to encapsulate that type and you get all the functionality that comes with List<T> (Add, Insert, Remove, etc.)

Comment: ah I completely understand! So i would only user something like 
public class DogList: List<Dog> if I wanted to say, remove every other dog from that list, or sort it a certain way. Does the above code look fine?

Comment: @Spooks: See update.  It's usually not necessary to create a class that derives from List<T>.  The only time that would be useful is if there were "groups" of Dogs (or whatever) that had special properties.  Even then, there are other techniques you can use to group types, like the Grouping extensions in LINQ or OfType<T>.

Answer (score 3):

Well, C# has a perfectly good `List<>` class already, so unless you have very specific needs I wouldn't go with a new DogList class. If you need to keep track of all created Dogs, then a static list inside the dog class is fine. Just make sure it's kept `private` and you have methods for adding or retrieving dogs. Better yet, your Dog factory can add them to the list for you (which I now see you mentioned yourself).

Comment: Dog factory? does that mean a class outside of the dog class?

Comment: Not necessarily, it can be a static method of the Dog class.

Answer (score 1):

> Or should the list be a static within
>   the original dog class? maybe in the
>   constructor, any time someone creates
>   a new dog, the dog gets put into the
>   static list?

This solution would work in a single-threaded application, but it would expose you to [all the dangers of global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

It would also be a poor abstraction<sup>*</sup>: when would it make sense for a `Dog` class contain a list of all the dogs any caller has constructed at runtime? What's supposed to happen if the caller de-allocates a `Dog` instance?

Instead, callers that will use a list of dogs should explicitly take responsibility for creating and managing it. Those callers will know the proper lifetime for the list, they'll be able to control what goes in the list, plus it will be obvious to anyone reading the code what's happening and how.

<sup>*</sup> Unless the list is supposed to be a log of dogs created.

Comment: Excellent, very well said. I didn't think it made sense.  You can view the way I finally made it above (obviously not actually using dogs, and simplified it a bit)